# Literature on Nuclear Operators and Hilbert Schmidt Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I have to trouble to find some literature on nuclear operators and Hilbert-Schmidt Operators. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks so much. Werner I already knew but the other I didn't. thanks so much!

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic content concerning these topics is included in

- Yosida: Functional Analysis,
- Reed Simon 1,
- Werner: Funktionalanalysis.